# Redis keep only top 50 elements in a sorted set

Tags: redis

Is it possible to, in a sorted set, keep only top x elements and remove others? I know ZREMRANGEBYRANK and ZREMRANGEBYSCORE but I couldn't figure out use these to remove everything but top x elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

do you mean something like

```
ZREMRANGEBYRANK set 0 -51
```

Comment: what if the scores are timestamps like 1526218200 '...data' 1526217300 '...data' 1526216400 '...data' etc